# How to get a value from a combobox in a form after the field is populated by the database

Tags: extjs

I have a formPanel with two of the form items as comboboxes with their stores populated by the database. The value from **comboBoxA** needs to be used to get the value for **comboBoxB** however comboBoxA.getValue() (as well as getRawValue()) are returning undefined.

```
storeA.load();

var comboBoxA = Ext.getCmp(comboBoxAID);
storeB.baseParams.UserID = comboBoxA.getValue();
storeB.load();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#method-Ext.data.Store-load), store loading is asynchronous, so you have to do your additional processing within the appropriate callback:

```
storeA.on('load', function(){
    var comboBoxA = Ext.getCmp(comboBoxAID);
    storeB.baseParams.UserID = comboBoxA.getValue();
    storeB.load();
});
storeA.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading a ComboBoxes store does not actually select a value. Try making a selection first (or loading a record into the form, etc). It sounds like your trying to link the 2 combos. If thats the case, search around for a tutorial, there are few out there. This should get you started, [Linked Combos](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Linked_Combos_Tutorial_for_Ext_2).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [this](http://www.sk-typo3.de/ExtJS-Dynamische-Comboboxen.337.0.html). It might be exactly what you are looking for. It also has a demo on the same page. The page is in german but the demo is predictable and the code is in english so test [this](http://www.sk-typo3.de/ExtJS-Dynamische-Comboboxen.337.0.html).